# How can I hide parent element of all elements with a given class, but the parent element also has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I want to hide all instances of an li element with class `parent` that have an immediate child div element with class `child-1`. Here's a pseudocode example, where the method `hideParent()` would hide the parent of the selected element(s):

```
$("li.parent > div.child-1").hideParent();
```

The following is an example of my HTML, in which the second and third `li.parent` elements should be hidden.

```
<li class="parent">
    <div class="child-0"> ... </div>
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="child-1"> ... </div>
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <div class="child-1"> ... </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li.parent > div.child-1").parent().hide();
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I should have thought of that and now feel silly for missing this simple solution. Worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select the relevant child elements directly, target their parents (filtered by the relevant selector), then hide them.

```
$("div.child-1").parent('li.parent').hide();
```

See:
[`parent` Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parent)

Comment: Also a helpful answer. Though the answer provided by Joe came in first, it was new info. to me that the `parent()` method can be filtered. I'm sure I'll use this in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with using `filter`:

```
$("li").filter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var isParent = $this.hasClass("parent");
    var childMatchCount = $this.children("div").filter(".child-1").length;
    return isParent && childMatchCount;
}).hide();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GEhfP/

Although this can be optimized in several ways. But to me, it's more "readable", in a very explicit sense. Using jsperf, the quickest I can get `filter` to work is with:

```
$("li.parent").filter(function () {
    return $(this).children("div.child-1").length;
}).hide();
```

@Joe's answer was the fastest with: `$("li.parent > div.child-1").parent()`